# Submitting data via AJAX or image before window unload

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out how to send data to an API on page unload either by AJAX or img (data in GET). I've done this successfully in the past with a synchronous AJAX call on unload, but there has to be a better way. Also, this way isn't working well enough for one site that I tried it on, where the window will not wait for the synchronous call no matter what I do.

Any ideas?

Comment: How large is your data?  Are you trying to save last good values, or just notify your page that the window is closed.  How about holding open a websocket (which the browser must close before leaving the page) ?

Comment: I'm trying to send data about the page visit (notably forms being sent) to my third party service. I decide to not send on form submit because the form may or may not pass validation. I send on page unload in the hope that it's validated by that point.

Comment: 1 thing I can think of is to maintain a list of all ids processed by the server in my current page load, and send those along with my data. The server would remove these ids from being processed so that only the most recent event would be considered.